# How to make background image in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

```
<html>
    <body>
        <li style="<?php echo base_url(); ?>background-image: url(images/slide11.jpg);"></li>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use CSS and images folders exist inside the asset folder. Then in your CSS file, you have to use below code.

```
background:url('../images/teksture2.png');
```

Comment: <li style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/slide11.jpg);"> here is correct answer .Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to the other answer you don't really need to go through base URL .......in your style.

Just use

Style="URL(../path/to/image) ;"
not absolute path. So basically there is an index.php in the root of of your application...from there define the path .,As all pages(classes(controllers)) directly run through index.php

For eg if your images was in the root folder you would use
URL(image.jpg)